# How to send parameters through href to the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, href

I have to send `id` in my controller like this:

```
<%=link_to(@active,{:controller => 'emppedes', :action=> 'index', :id => @id})%>
```

but using `href` instead of `link_to`. If I do this with `href`:

```
<a href="/emppedes">
```

the `id` is not sent.

```
<a href="/ emppedes :id => @id">
```

does not work. How can I send `id` through `href`?

Comment: I think link_to is the improved version of href in Rails . You can try : <%= link_to "Your link", emppedes_path(:id => @id) %> . Then in your url Rails will insert something like ../index?id=3 . Also you can access :id in your controllers and partials .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use the `link_to` helper? Anyway, you probably want:

```
<a href="/emppedes?id=<%=@id%>">
```

But i strongly recommend against using raw tags for links inside your app. I'm sure you can achieve everything with the `link_to` helper, too. Please give an example why you think you can't use it.

---

(In reply to your comment) I would do it this way:

```
<%= content_tag :li, :class => ( 'active' if @active == "personaldetails" ) do %>
  <%= link_to '/emppedes', :id => @id do %>
    <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>
    Personal Details
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I use link_to also in my Project. Here i use href in less place. I am using side navigation bar in bootstrap inside my project where href is suited for best place of css Hence.

Comment: So your problem is, that you want to set a css class on the link? You can do this with `link_to(@active,{:controller => ...}, :class => 'my_css_class')`

Comment: <li class="<% if @active == "personaldetails" %><%= "active" %><% end %>">
 <a href="/emppedes?id=<%=@id%>">

  <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>
Personal Details
</a>
 </li>    It is working perfectly ok how can i make it work by using link_to?